# Make div's vertically fit inside parent div, with a scrollbar on one

Tags: html, css

I would like to have two divs inside a container fit vertically to fill the parent container, without overflowing from the bottom.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="parent-container">
    <div class="div1" style="height:auto;width:100%;">
      <span style="width:100%;">
        <div class="td-div">Header Test 1</div>
        <div class="td-div">Header Test 12</div>
        <div class="td-div">Header Test 1 3</div>
        <div class="td-div">Header Test 14</div>
        <div class="td-div">Header Test 15</div>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="div2" style="width:100%;overflow-y:auto;">
        <div class="blue-row" style= "width:100%;">
          <span style="width:100%;display:inline-block">
            <div class="td-div">TEst1 testing seeing what happens when its long</div>
            <div class="td-div">Test2</div>
            <div class="td-div">Test 3 3</div>
            <div class="td-div">Test 4</div>
            <div class="td-div">T e s t 5</div>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="blue-row" style="width:100%;"> 
          <span style="width:100%;display:inline-block">
            <div class="td-div">TEst1 testing seeing what happens when its long</div>
            <div class="td-div">Test2</div>
            <div class="td-div">Test 3 3</div>
            <div class="td-div">Test 4</div>
            <div class="td-div">T e s t 5</div>
          </span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The link below is the actual problem that I'm having , with a bit more CSS to make it easier to distinguish.

http://jsfiddle.net/8sdLe2pu/12/

The problem is that the div with class "div2" is overflowing out the bottom of the parent container.  It should fill any space left in the container (the space that the header doesn't take up) and should have a scrollbar to be able to view the rest of the contents.

I would like it to look like this example below, except it should vertically fill it's container, and should NOT use a hard-coded percent on the div with class "div2".

http://jsfiddle.net/8sdLe2pu/10/

It should look similar to this above, except there should be NO red space below the div with the scrollbar (div2). It should automatically fill the parent container without overflowing.

So, my question is, would it be possible to make a child div have a scrollbar like in the JSFiddle example number 10, while at the same time having it fill the parent without overflowing, and without using a hard-coded % height.

I do not want to use a hard-coded % height, because it should be able to always fill the parent container regardless of screen size, and the parent container uses vh for it's height.

Comment: look into css flexbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution using flexbox.

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.modal-body{
  height:65vh;
  background:red;
}
.parent-container{
  width:100%; height:100%;   
  display:flex;
  align-items:stretch;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.div1{
  background:green;
}
.div2{
  flex:1;
  background:blue;
}
.div1 span{
  display:table;
}
.div1 span div{
  display:table-cell;
  width:20%;
  padding:1em;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

div.blue-row span{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
div.blue-row span div{
  display:table-cell;
  width:20%;
  padding:1em;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

And working demo can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/pulamc/x8xw2hLg/

Answer (score 0):

I used a bit of javascript to pull the height of your containing div out of the DOM and apply it to the .div2 class. also instead of a % height on div1 I used its current pixel height which is 75px.

basically subtract 75px ( or whatever height you end up with for the portion above your table ) from the total height of the containing div and put that in as the css height of the .div2

With this method the height will be calculated each time the page loads so it should always fit within the element instead of being hardcoded.

**::Fiddle::**
https://jsfiddle.net/8sdLe2pu/38/

**::Code::**

::JS:: --> used jQuery

```
var $modalBody = $( '.modal-body' ),
    modalHeight = $modalBody.height(),
    $div2 = $( '.div2' ),
    div2Height = $div2.css( 'height' );

$div2.css({
    height: modalHeight - 75
});

$( window ).resize(function(){
    if ( div2Height !== modalHeight - 75 ){
         $div2.css({
            height: modalHeight - 75
        });
    }
});
```

::CSS::

```
.modal-body {
    height:65vh;
    background: red;
}
.td-div {
    width:19%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.div2 {
}
```

::HTML:: --> only made this one adjustment

```
<div class="div1" style="height:75px;width:100%;">
```

Comment: This works, but I was trying to avoid using JavaScript for this issue, since I knew it would (or should) be possible using only CSS and HTML